# How to Submit Form into Bootstrap Modal (send POST method into Modal) Laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying for 2 days but still no luck!

I want to

- Submit Form from index.php to result.php
- Show result.php inside Modal while index.php is open! (without
  closing index.php)

here is example code!

> index.php

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="result.php" target="_blank">
<input type="text" name="userId" id="userId"/>
<input id="button" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

> result.php

```
    <div id="resultModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                 <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>ESC</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Show Result </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">



            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

In Modal body

```
<?php  $selectedId = $_POST['userId']; 
    echo  $selectedId; 
?>
```

And JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(ev) {
        var userId = $('#userId').find("input").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : $(this).attr('action'),
            data: userId,
            success: function () {
              // alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not quiet sure what you want to achieve here with form but here is how you can show some content from remote page in modal [link](www.tutsme-webdesign.info/bootstrap-3-modal-displaying-remote-content/)[/link] . If that is what you mean...

Comment: Not exactly! Basically i want to load data from database  depend on  user input! and show result on Modal (using remote content)

Comment: Currently I don't see where you are trying to trigger your modal from. This needs to be done by JavaScript with something like this.`$('#resultModal').modal('show')`. I also don't see how you handle the returned data from your Ajax call. Currently you're just calling `result.php` but you do nothing with what it returns. This can be done in `.done()` function for example and this would also be a good place to start the modal as well. Check out http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods for details.

Answer (score 3):

Well it has taken me some time but I think I found an answer to your question, or at least this solution can give you a good clue on how to continue with what you are doing.

First index.php: Here you need to have your form with an input field and one button, which we will call modal, and submit form (using Ajax for post)

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <div id="userDiv"><label>UserId</label>
         <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" placeholder="UserId"/> <br></div>
    <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Send Data</button>
</form>
```

Then you need a modal where you will put content from remote page. In modal-body you add one more div tag with id="bingo" to locate him easy :) like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">MyModal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="bingo"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This page also needs to have a script tag which will do the job. **Important** it must be placed **after** the script tag where you load the jquery file.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            var vUserId = $("#userId").val();
         if(vUserId=='')
         {
             alert("Please enter UserId");
         }
         else{
            $.post("result.php", //Required URL of the page on server
               { // Data Sending With Request To Server
                  user:vUserId,
               },
         function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
             $("#bingo").html(response);//"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
             $("#form")[0].reset();
          });
        }
     });
   });
</script>
```

And last but not the least result.php:

```
<?php
   if($_POST["user"])
   {
        $user = $_POST["user"];
       // Here, you can also perform some database query operations with above values.
       echo "Your user id is: ". $user;
  }
?>
```

P.S. I hope I didn't mess somewhere with ids, variables or similar because I tried to adjust the solution to your example. I hope this is what you need, or at least this will be a clue to accomplish your task. Still think that this could be done on one page but it was interesting for me to try to find a way to make this work... GL!

Comment: Thank you for your time Aleksandar! Just because I am working on Laravel project that reason I couldn't show all my code here.I couldn't make your code working but maybe I am missing something! So I will check deeply.

Comment: You're welcome. Well it's work fine for me, i will check if i miss something one more time but i think i didn't... I hope you will make it work. I have problem with <script> tag at first i put <script src=jquer> after this script with ajax code accidentally so it's caused me a problem and take some time, i believe it's something small like that. So, if you already didn't place it like that, first <script src=jquer.js> than <script>Ajax code</script> than <script src=bootstrap.js>....

Comment: There is no problem to load script and modal pop up window.But I cant get remote content.Only empty modal window loading which is located in index.php

Comment: I just test it and it's work just fine, is there a way to sand you my php source files? I'm new here so i don't know if it's possible.

Comment: I didn't upload here because of Laravel project.So not many people use Laravel. I ll find the way to show you source code, I will be available lately.Thank you again Aleksandar!

Comment: And again you're welcome. Sorry for my English I want to send my index.php and result.php to you so you can check what's happened there to compere code... :) sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: So sorry my bad! I was in rush so couldn't read carefully! Here is one of the best online code tester https://jsfiddle.net/ Regards

Comment: I can't there write php code so here is dropbox link [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zsrgyziyh7qrsvx/AAA8QRX6LuXqj5YVEHzEG7iFa?dl=0) to this two file, download them and try to see if it's work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73103/discussion-between-royertan-and-aleksandar-miladinovic).