# Mysqli Update statement not updating database no error

Tags: php, html, ajax

I've tried different ways/statement approaches to get this update statement to work but I have no clue what`s going on... The database is not getting updated and no errors appear. Nothing happens. Something is really wrong.

```
//editDetails
if(isset($_POST['editDetails'])){

//bind parameters
$updatecompany = $db->prepare("UPDATE company SET `title`=?, `description`=?, `address`=?, `type`=?, `country`=?, `timezone`=? WHERE `id`=?");
$updatecompany->bind_param('ssssss',$_POST['title'],$_POST['type'],$_POST['description'],$_POST['address'],$_POST['country'],$_POST['timezone']);
$updatecompany->execute();

    // set parameters and execute
    $companyid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["id"]);
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["title"]);
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["type"]);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["description"]);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["address"]);
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["country"]);
    $timezone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["timezone"]);

if($updatecompany){
 // echo "Data Submitted succesfully";
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;
  }
$updatecompany->close();
$db->close();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
//editDetails
if(isset($_POST['editDetails'])){

//bind parameters
$updatecompany = $db->prepare("UPDATE company SET `title`=?, `description`=?, `address`=?, `type`=?, `country`=?, `timezone`=? WHERE `id`=?");
$updatecompany->bind_param('ssssssi',$_POST['title'],$_POST['description'],$_POST['address'],$_POST['type'],$_POST['country'],$_POST['timezone'],$_POST['id']);
$updatecompany->execute();

    // set parameters and execute
    $companyid = $_POST["id"];
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    $timezone = $_POST["timezone"];

if($updatecompany){
 // echo "Data Submitted succesfully";
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;
  }
$updatecompany->close();
$db->close();
}
```

**form.php**

```
 <form id="editDetails" method="POST" action="core/query.php">
<table>
<thead></thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php while($company=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
  <tr>
      <td data-th="Name"><?=$company['title'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Description"><?=$company['description'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Type"><?=$company['type'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Address"><?=$company['address'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Country"><?=$company['country'];?></td>
    <td data-th="Time Zone"><?=$company['timezone'];?></td>
    <td data-th="ID" sorttable_customkey="2"><button id='editCompanyDetails'  class='btn btn-default btn-sm' type='button'  name='companyDetails' data-toggle="modal"data-target="#myModal2" title='Edit details'>
     <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
<input name="companyid" type="hidden" type="hidden" class="formBlock btn btn-success"  value="<?=$company['id'];?>"/>
  </tr>
    <?php };?>
 </tbody>
<tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<input id='title' class='form-control formBlock' name='title' value='' type='text' placeholder="Name...">
 <select id='type' class='form-control formBlock' name='type'></select>
 <select id='type' class='form-control formBlock' name='description'></select>
 <input id='address' class='form-control formBlock' name='address' value='' type='text' placeholder="Address">
<select name="country"  id='country' class='form-control formBlock' name='country' value='' type='text' placeholder="Country"></select>
  <select id='timezone' class='form-control formBlock' name="timezone"></select>
<input name="editDetails" id="submit" type="submit" class="formBlock btn btn-success"  value="Modify Data"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: You arent checking for errors. Count the `?` and the `s`s, looks like you forgot to bind the `id`. I'm also not clear what you are doing after the `execute` but your comment `// set parameters and execute` is wrong, the execute already occurred and there's no need for escaping.

Comment: why are you even using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` if you're using a prepared statement? do the POSTs have values?

Comment: count your `?`'s / POST arrays and binds; it's failing. 7 != 6. Had you checked for errors, it would have told you about it. Most specifically for the `WHERE` clause. Take this as the answer to this. Edit: @chris85 I didn't see your edit when I was typing this one out *lol*

Comment: add an `else{ echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($db); }` and you just Stealth edited this question. I'm out.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: What but I thought I needed to edit when you guys offer suggestions.

Comment: comments already posted by @chris85 and myself were made before your edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42477320/2 and during the orginal post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42477320/1

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I need to put it back? I will.

Comment: You used this code and it didn't update? Are you using error reporting now?

Comment: use error reporting and the `else` I posted.

Comment: @chris85: I use this first line on top `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` I see nothing.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Does it make a difference if the form that submit data is in a modal? Even if the modal is inside of the form...?

Comment: I rarely use `mysqli`, I'm going off the syntax and question history here. If you were using that previously then it is failing you, use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php, as @Fred-ii- posted. Placeholders and bindings always need to match up.

Comment: that may very be the clincher to all this. post your full code and exactly how it's used. If it runs as pure php without the modal, then that's why it's failing

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I'll have a try without the modal first.

Comment: Developing without error reporting is hard to do. Use an invalid query first so you can confirm error reporting is working.

Comment: @chris85: nothing typically happens.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I edited with form.php. I did not put the options otherwise it would be too long.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066537/how-to-submit-form-into-bootstrap-modal-send-post-method-into-modal-laravel I have to use Ajax. I did not want to but I think I will.

Comment: Ajax will probably not solve your issue on its own. If you added the proper error handling as already commented, the next question is: is there a valid ID? You can check how many rows was affected by the query with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

Comment: You also seem to have some weird, and somewhere invalid, HTML. Although that alone likely isn't the cause of your issue. **Edit**: `id`! = `companyid`, and I can't find anywhere that `$_POST['id']` is ever being set

Comment: How do you know your problem is mysqli or SQL related? Do you have all variables properly set by the time of query execution? Care to verify them first?

Comment: @Qirel: WHat you're saying is interesting but I don't understand... you mean to say id != companyid? How? It refers to `<input name="companyid" type="hidden" class="formBlock btn btn-success"  value="<?=$company['id'];?>"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everybody for helping. I got the query to work with following code.

```
//editDetails
if(isset($_POST['editDetails'])){

    // set parameters and execute
    $companyid = $_POST["companyid"];
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    $timezone = $_POST["timezone"];

    $updatecompany = "UPDATE company SET title = '$title', type='$type', description='$description', address='$address', country='$country', timezone='$timezone' WHERE id='$companyid'";
    mysqli_select_db($db, 'mydb');
    $resultq = mysqli_query($db, $updatecompany);

if(! $resultq ){
 die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($db));
}
$db->close();
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;
  }
```